# How to retrieve data from sqlite3 database filled up using Python?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, peewee

I am using peewee along with flask to populate my database with user's inputs and various other stats. How can I retrieve the data in sqlite3 database? 
Here is the skeleton:

```
from peewee import *
database = SqliteDatabase('app4.db', autocommit=True)
class BaseModel(Model):
 class Meta:
  database = database    

class Model1(BaseModel):

class Model2(BaseModel):

class Model3(BaseModel):

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.before_request
def func1():
 database.connect()

@app.after_request
def func2(response):
 database.close()
 return response 

@app.route('/', method= ['GET'])
def some_func():
 #update pluto and create instances of Model2 and Model3 here

if __name__ == "__main__":
 database.connect()
 database.create_tables([Model1, Model2, Model3], True)
 pluto, created = Model1.get_or_create(key = 2, key2 = 0)
```

My app is running and showing the updated instances of Model1 and Model2 which means that it has created the models and is continually updating the database. 
But I don't know how to retrieve this data offline.

When I enter my sqllite database by `sqlite3 app4.db` and type `.tables` it shows me all the tables i.e. Model1, Model2, Model3 but typing in the query : `select * from model1;` gives nothing. I tried retrieving the data in Ipython shell too making a connection to database as above and querying `list(Model1.select())` but it gives an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your database filename is being set to `app.py`:

```
database = SqliteDatabase('app.py', autocommit=True)
```

It should probably be `app4.db` if that's what you want to use:

```
database = SqliteDatabase('app4.db', autocommit=True)
```

Comment: SOrry for the confusion. It is actually set to app4.db

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the right `app4.db` file? It may be relative to the `app.py` file.

Comment: Actually, I am indeed very sure abt this. I just checked it again. I think it might not be saving the state of database. Can you suggest some ways to make sure that database is saved after every transaction? I thought autocommit =True had the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The commands you are using look like the correct ones for doing it at the command line. Sounds to me like either 1 of 2 things are happening:

1. You are not actually putting data into the databases
2. You are not viewing the same database that you are populating.

Try renaming the app4.db file, and re-running your app and see if it creates a new one. This way you can make sure you are using sqlite3 on the correct one. If you are still not seeing any data using the commands you listed, I would assume that your app is not actually putting the data into the tables.